# How can I detect if a thread has windows handles?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, gdi, spy++

How can I programmatically detect if a thread has windows handles on it for a given process?

spy++ gives me this information but I need to do it programmatically.

I need to do this in C#, however the .net diagnostics libs don't give me this information. I imagine spy++ is using some windows api call that I don't know about.

I have access to the code of the system I'm trying to debug. I want to embed some code called by a timer periodically that will detect how many thread contain windows handles and log this info.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use win api functions: [EnumWindowsProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(VS.85).aspx) to iterate through window handles and [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx) to get the thread id and process id associated with given window handle

Please check if an example below would work for you:

this code iterates through processes and threads using System.Diagnostics; for each thread ID I'm calling GetWindowHandlesForThread function (see code below)

```
foreach (Process procesInfo in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    Console.WriteLine("process {0} {1:x}", procesInfo.ProcessName, procesInfo.Id);
    foreach (ProcessThread threadInfo in procesInfo.Threads)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tthread {0:x}", threadInfo.Id);
        IntPtr[] windows = GetWindowHandlesForThread(threadInfo.Id);
        if (windows != null && windows.Length > 0)
            foreach (IntPtr hWnd in windows)
                Console.WriteLine("\t\twindow {0:x}", hWnd.ToInt32());
    }
}
```

GetWindowHandlesForThread implementation:

```
private IntPtr[] GetWindowHandlesForThread(int threadHandle)
{
    _results.Clear();
    EnumWindows(WindowEnum, threadHandle);
    return _results.ToArray();
}

private delegate int EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.Dll")]
private static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc x, int y);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out int processId);

private List<IntPtr> _results = new List<IntPtr>();

private int WindowEnum(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
{          
    int processID = 0;
    int threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processID);
    if (threadID == lParam) _results.Add(hWnd);
    return 1;
}
```

result of the code above should dump into console smth like this:

```
...
process chrome b70
    thread b78
        window 2d04c8
        window 10354
...
    thread bf8
    thread c04
...
```