# When I close Powershell window, it closes VS Code

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I have a interesting problem.  When I run a powershell script for the start of my day (ExampleStartupScript.ps1) it runs and will give me this: [Completed Script and then a bunch of Utility Processes...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImeIX.png)

It stays open if I do nothing, even when I have a 'Exit' or a 'stop-process' command in the script to end the script. The window will not close.   I will close it manually and it will also close my Visual Studio Code app window as well.   Is there a reason for this?

The line that I have for VSCode is:

```
Start-process -filepath "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

I do have VSCode set to run as an Administrator when opened as well.

Ideally what I want to have happen is my script runs, opens what I needs and then closes when finished. But I have to manually close the window and reopen VSCode.  It's not a breaking thing but it is a oddity.

- VScode Version 1.77.3
- Powershell 7-x64 7.3.4.0

---What I have tried & Expect---

Adding `Exit` at the end of the script does nothing.

Tried `Stop-process -name Pwsh -force`

Tried `stop-process -name Pwsh 1068`...(the number related to the task manager app number.)  There are 2 that come up but might revisit...

Overall, I expect my script to open when I log in which it does, it opens the apps I need for the day, and then I want it to close. (but it does not close automatically.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i just checked what is lauchned from cmd with.

```
where code
```

Interesting result is that, if you launch it from cmd.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd
```

The code.cmd is started and not the Code.exe from the root of the install.

This should do what you want

```
Start-process -filepath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" -NoNewWindow
```

After this you can do (--new-windows as example for the code commandline options)

```
Start-process -filepath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" -ArgumentList "--new-window"
```

The command in the code.cmd are necessary to detach the console session from the exe. So, I advise to do it as originally intended.

Closing vscode than could be more or less complicated, depending on your specific requirements.

A real good example how to manage windows can be found here. [How can I kill the child process without PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973397/how-can-i-kill-the-child-process-without-pid). But in your case you have a PID so most of the code may not needed.

The basic answer is send WMClose to the correct windows, but a process may have many windows.

But maybe **KILL $PID** is enough for you.

```
KILL $PID
```