# C# - Capturing user clicks on other application

Tags: c#, automation, click, recording

I need to create a program that can record user clicks for another Windows application. Essentially my program should read a data file and automatically run another application and enter the data. I understand that there are process automation tools but they are prohibitively expensive for one-time use. For refernce of this forum a simimar question was asked in past but was not answered so recreating it.

[Capturing user events (button clicks etc) from another Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679307/capturing-user-events-button-clicks-etc-from-another-windows-application)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx

check this reference, for some time UI Automation is built in into VS. You don't have to rely on expensive tools to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need global mouse event listener.
Something like this:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C