# How can I detect the fact of creation of menu/child window and get it's handle. (for external application)?

Tags: c#, winapi, menu, contextmenu, childwindow

I'm sending mouse down signal (for left or right button) to an external application. And if in the result of this action any type of menu or child window is created I want to get it's handle.

How can I do something like this?

And is it possible to detect the fact that application is about to open menu prior to the fact of opening the menu?

Comment: [Spy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4038730/1997232) does that. Search for `c# spy handle` (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1967604/1997232)).

Comment: So to perform EnumChildWindows looking for windows with class #32770 and #32768 after click would be enogh to capture any menu/child window?
One more thing - is it possible to detect the fact that application is about to open menu prior to the fact of opening the menu?

Comment: Use [hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38523/How-to-Write-a-Managed-Global-Hook-for-Window-Crea) (for `WM_CREATE`).