# c++ hooking to a different application, how to find thread id from process id?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, hook

I would like to add a hook to an application. I am using `SetWindowsHookEx` and I can create a system wide hook, but I want to create a hook for a particular application. I need to have thread id of the target application to hook it. I know title of the window, I know exe name and from these I can get window handle and process id, but how do I get the thread id? I saw a post about how to do it in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922982/how-can-i-detect-if-a-thread-has-windows-handles), but I do not see how to get a list of threads in c++.

```
HWND windowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, _T("SomeOtherApp"));
DWORD processId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, NULL);
DWORD threadId = ??? // How do I get thread id here?
HHOOK hook = ::SetWindowsHookEx( WH_CBT, HookCBTProc, hInst, threadId);
```

Thanks,
Alexander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetWindowThreadProcessId()` returns the thread ID. You are erroneously assigning the thread ID to the process ID variable. Instead write:

```
HWND windowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, _T("SomeOtherApp"));
DWORD threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, NULL);
HHOOK hook = ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, HookCBTProc, hInst, threadId);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was over complicating things.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `GetWindowThreadProcessId`. It takes the window handle and returns the ID of the thread that created the window and optionally the process ID.

Comment: That's right. Thanks for pointing it. I have corrected the answer.