# How do I retrieve the ThreadID shown in Spy++

Tags: c#, .net

I'm sure this is a hugely simple question. If I view a program in Spy++ I can see a Thread ID. When running my application, how do I get this (it's own Thread ID, not anothers)

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922982/how-can-i-detect-if-a-thread-has-windows-handles

Comment: @DanielKelley Looks handy, but to clarify, I only need the ThreadID of my own application.

Comment: This is already answered here I believe;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679243/getting-the-thread-id-from-a-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is GetCurrentThreadId():

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx?ppud=4