# C# Get a Pointer by using a Thread ID

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, dllimport, handle

EDIT3:
I need a list from all windows a thread has. Not FindWindowsEnum() because it only returns Top level Windows.... I need the window handle befor it's visible
END EDIT3

EDIT2:
Short desciption: I need a method, where i can get a "window handle" from a thread.

END EDIT2:

EDIT: 
First of all i can't use FindWindowsEnum()!!!
Because it only returns the top windows. I have to kill the window befor it is visible. So i have to get The Handle of the window by a Thread ID.
EDIT END:

I got a problem by a window which i have to close which is not focused or something like that. I have to close the window as it pops up. I only use code.

What i got:

This is the extern class where I import one dll and some functions which use the functions from the dll.

```
    class FindWindowApi
{
    //[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    //public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    public IntPtr[] GetWindowHandlesForThread(int threadHandle)
    {
        _results.Clear();
        EnumWindows(WindowEnum, threadHandle);
        return _results.ToArray();
    }

    public  delegate int EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    public static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc x, int y);

    public List<IntPtr> _results = new List<IntPtr>();

    public int WindowEnum(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
    {

        _results.Add(hWnd);
        return 1;
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(
        IntPtr handle,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder caption,
        int count);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr handle);

    public const UInt32 WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
}
```

at this class i use the functions from the extern class.

I start a Thread which runs every 10 milli secounds and kill a window in another method.

```
    public Disk_UC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread killit = new Thread(this.killIt);
        killit.Start();
        comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        comboBox2.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        Thread nt = new Thread(this.fillData);
        nt.Start();

    }

    //Thread Method
    private void killIt()
    {
        bool blac = false;
        Int32 oldThreadID = threadID;
        FindWindowApi api = new FindWindowApi();
        while ((!blac) 
            && (!MainDiag.isGoingDown))
        {
            if (oldThreadID != threadID)
            {

                IntPtr[] windows = api.GetWindowHandlesForThread(threadID);
                if (windows != null && windows.Length > 0)
                    foreach (IntPtr hWnd in windows)
                    {
                        killWindow(hWnd, threadID);
                    }

            }
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }   

    //Method which calls all the extern dll stuff
    private bool killWindow(IntPtr handle, int param)
    {
        var length = FindWindowApi.GetWindowTextLength(handle);
        var caption = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
        FindWindowApi.GetWindowText(handle, caption, caption.Capacity);

        IntPtr windowPtr = FindWindowApi.FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, caption.ToString());
        if (windowPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return false;
        }
        FindWindowApi.SendMessage(windowPtr, FindWindowApi.WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        return true;
    }
```

My Problem is now how can i get this specific window handle.
when the Thread "fillData" pops up the window. So i save the thread ID from this Thread fillData.

Now i call the other Methods with this thread id. I got the Thread ID and i get so many windows from the Process. But i need this specific window from **that thread.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect if a thread has windows handles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922982/how-can-i-detect-if-a-thread-has-windows-handles)

Comment: with EnumWindowsProc i dont get the Window i need....

Comment: This is very confused, and almost impossible to make sense of. Please step back and explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve, and how your current attempts fail.

Comment: The thread "fill data" use another .dll in this dll is an error. When this error occured, the Thread will be paused and an error messagebox appears. I can't edit the code from this dll.

Comment: Now i implemented a new thread which runs parallel to kill the error messagebox. But i dont get the Handle of this Messagebox. I only got a threadID and a processid. I have to kill this Messagebox befor it appears. The EnumWindowsProc method only returns a window which is already visible. What i need is a handle on this MessageBox only by using a ThreadID and/or a ProcessID. By the way in this programm are 10 own implemented threads. Please help me .dll import is alowed too.

Comment: "Kill it before it appears" sounds like a race condition that is hard to get right. On Windows this is nearly impossible if the messagebox creating code does not provide some kind of hook.

Comment: The code in the Thread "filData" will be paused when the messageBox appears. The MessageBox will be build. Befor its visible i can close it. But i first of all i need the Handle of this MessageBox.

Comment: You cannot turn a thread id into a window handle directly because a single thread can service multiple windows. So you need to enumerate them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922982/how-can-i-detect-if-a-thread-has-windows-handles I am not sure it will list the messagebox but it is worth a try.

Comment: I tried to enumerate them ... and in the description i tried to say that this dont get me the window i want -.-

Comment: aaaaand i can say that this thread only have one Window